# newcolumntype, siunitx, tabu and illegal pream-tokens

Tags: tables, siunitx, tabu

I use `tabu` with `siunitx` for making my charts with MikTeX 2.9, `tabu` 2.8 and now `siunitx` v2.5g. Since last time using the updater `\newcolumn` commands like

```
\newcolumntype D{X[1,c]{%
  S[group-four-digits=true,
  table-format=2.0e1,
  per-mode=symbol]}}
\tabucolumn D
```

don't work anymore but raise error messages like

```
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token.
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can anyone help me?

This is the not-working-anymore minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=12]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\usepackage{tabu}
\newcolumntype D{X[1,c]{S[group-four-digits=true,table-format = 2.0e1,per-mode=symbol]}}
\tabucolumn D

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {XDDX}
    \toprule
    one & {two two two two two} & {three three} & four\\
    1.23456 & 1.23456 & 1.23456 & 1.23456 \\
    1.2 & 1.2 & 1.2 & 1.2 \\
    999.9 &999.9 &999.9 &999.9\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Hint: using

```
\newcolumnD{X[1.c]S[...
```

(without the curly bracket) as described in other threads does not work, as it is interpreted as columns X and S as substitution for D.

Comment: I can confirm that with TeX Live 2011 it works, but not with the 2012 version; I suspect something related to the newly released `siunitx`. On the other hand, I don't think that enlarging a table to the line width is necessary: a table should be as wide as it needs to be.

Comment: egreg is right. I reverted to older package versions and found out the following:

 - `siunitx v2.5c (2012/05/03)` with `expl3 (2011/09/05)` from the corresponding l3kernel and l3packages works well

 - `siunitx v2.5g (2012/07/22)` with `expl3 (2012/07/16)` from the corresponding l3kernel and l3packages do not work with the code above

Answer (score 10):

This happens because `tabu` does something that the LaTeX3 approach specifically forbids: it uses an internal macro from `siunitx`.

In the revision from v2.5e to v2.5f, the internals of `siunitx` were marked up as 'private', following the LaTeX3 naming scheme. This does not show up as `tabu` does a csname-based assignment, and this is silently converted to `\relax` by TeX.  It can be 'fixed' by doing

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn \__siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

after loading `siunitx`.

Comment: This workaround does not work anymore with the latest `siunitx`. Here is a question  pleading for a new one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603267/82186