# Embedding siunitx v3 S column into tabu X

Tags: tables, siunitx, tabu

`tabu`'s documentation promises it can embed an `S` column (from `siunitx`) into an `X` column with the following syntax: `X[c]{S[...]}`.

When `siunitx` went from `v2.5e` to `v2.5f` a workaround became necessary: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70323/82186

With more recent `siunitx` versions (the latest being `v3.0.16`) the workaround does not work anymore.

Is it possible make `tabu` collaborate again with another hack?

Here is a MNWE with the outdated workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn \__siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{cX[c]{S[explicit-sign=+]}}
   a & 1 \\
   b & 2.2 \\
   c & 3.33 \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Here is the error it produces:

```
! Argument of \__siunitx_table_collect_begin:w has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.13 \begin{tabu}{XX[c]{S[explicit-sign=+]}}
```

Comment: tabu is broken and unmaintained. Don't use it. See the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. I know it's unmaintained (and unfortunately I cannot step forward to help with that). A big chunk of the document class I'm trying to fix has already been written using `tabu`, so I took a shot and asked the question hoping to avoid a difficult rewrite.

Comment: I think you are likely best using `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]` if you _must_ use `tabu`: the code in the latter makes some low-level assumptions about `siunitx` internals, and I don't see a quick fix

Comment: the main problem is not that it is unmaintained, but that it is broken in various parts. Look at the issue list. Using that in one document may work, using it in a class is irresponsible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may replace the outdated `tabu` package with the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray). Support for `siunitx` package was added in version 2021L of `tabularray` package. (Already submitted to CTAN, need one or two days to reach TeX Live.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{cX[c,si={explicit-sign=+}]}
   a & 1    \\
   b & 2.2  \\
   c & 3.33 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```